# How To Create This Type of Structure in html css and bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to be code HTML CSS and bootstrap

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/ ... yes it's the documentation that you have to read

Answer (score -1):

This is the [document to learn navbar in bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp).

```css
.foicon{
  color: skyblue;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.foicon1{
  color: white;
}
.navbar-brand{font-size:14px !important;}
.navbar-nav {
  float: right !important;
}
.quote{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: skyblue;
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.quote:hover{
  background: skyblue !important;
}
.nav > li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 15px 2px !important;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <title>Bootstrap</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="setest_style.css">
   <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-6 navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope foicon"></i>admin@website.com</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone foicon"></i>051514440000</a>
    </div>
    <ul class=" nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook foicon1"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter foicon1"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google foicon1"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube foicon1"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="quote">get a quote</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May I know why this answer got downvoted ? was trying since hours for this and you reward me with down vote?